# Mitt event bus, not working inside axios interceptor but works fine in my vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm working with **VueJs** and **mitt** for the **eventBus**, the mitt is loaded globally as you can see and works fine :

**main.js**

```
const emitter = mitt();

const app = createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter
```

I call the eventBus in all my component like that : it works fine
this.emitter.emit('eventName', data)

My problem is when I use that inside axios interceptor I get an error ( undefined )

my **client.js**  ( axios instance )

```
const client = axios.create({
    // withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: ((authenticated.data.domain !== null) ? authenticated.data.domain : 'http://mydomain.test/api')
});

client.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
      // problem is here 
     this.emitter.emit('alert', response.data);

    return response;
}, (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error.message);
});

export default client;
```

Comment: an axios instance is not a Vue isntance - perhaps add `window.emitter = emitter;` in `main.js` and then just use `emitter.emit` - though, that's a bit hacky, but since there's no indication of which version of Vue you're using, nor if this `mitt` can be used as a module, that's the best I can come up with

Comment: @Bravo I'm using Vue 3

Comment: @Bravo Doesn't works :(  can you clarify please

Comment: to clarify I'd just say exactly the same thing - it's as clear as it will ever be - the point is I don't know enough about how your vue app is set up to provide any more help - i.e. are you using a build system? if so, which one. Is mitt available in esmodule flavour?

Comment: `mitt` does come in esmodule flavour - so if you're using js type module (i.e. import/export) - then I would suggest using mitt esmodule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.config.globalProperties` is used to create globals off of *Vue component instances* (not globals off `window`). You're incorrectly trying to use the global event bus in your Axios instance, as the `this` in that arrow function is `undefined`.

One solution is to factor out the event bus, and import it where needed:

```js
// emitter.js
import mitt from 'mitt'
export default mitt()
```

```js
// main.js
          
import emitter from './emitter.js'

const app = createApp(App)              
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter
```

```js
// client.js
         
import emitter from './emitter.js'
⋮
client.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
       
    emitter.emit('alert', response.data);

    return response;
}, (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error.message);
});
```